# Is there any other way of using signed applets

Tags: java, class, applet, loader, signed

If I want to deploy high privileged applets they need to be signed. For that a certificate is created and then a jar file is signed with a jarsigner. After that in the HTML code one has to specify code,codebase AND archive (jar) which we signed before.

However I wrote a servlet which acts as two things:

1. it sits at the URL pointed by the codebase and serves class bytecode to the applet.
2. The same servlet also uses serialization to communicate with the applet whereby whenever the applet gets a class it does not know it goes to the codebase which ends up back at the servlet.

Almost like a mini RMI setup but simpler. I hope you can see the power in this.

Unfortunately for signed applets one needs the archive. Now the servlet is also able to load a Certificate object and can send it to the applet too. So here is the setup: At one point the applet receives class bytecode and it also has the Certificate. It would be nice if the applet could instantiate all received classes using that certificate (otherwise code from jar is signed and outside is not which prompts nasty messages to the user).

**So my question to you fine Java aficionados:**
   Would there by any way for me to use the bytecode data and the Certificate to instantiate the class as a signed object so that the plugin pops the Security dialog, accepts teh certificate and elevates the object's privileges. What I could find is that the there is a class CodeSource that accepts codebase URL and certificate and is essential to the signing process. What I am not sure is how one could intercept the class loading inside applets to install additional certificates not obtained through a JAR file via archive.

What do you say?
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced of the use of loading classes that are generated on-the-fly.

Having said that, a simple yet dangerous way to make classes have full-access is to call ..

```
System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

.. in an early stage of the applet init().  That would fail in a sand-boxed applet, but will work in a trusted applet.

A better (safer) way to achieve the desired result would be to implement a custom security manager - one that provides elevated privileges only to the code coming from the server.

Implementing a security manager might seem daunting, but it is easy to make a trivial one.  See this reply to the [System.ext()](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-programmer/11837/System-ext#1xgukg8a6mu4a1pr7ru6hokq1ddlg40tudenet) thread from comp.lang.java.programming for an example.